# Notice: Undefined index utilizando POST en php

Tags: php, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Enviar Datos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="procesaDatos.php" method="post">
        Nombre:
        <br>
 <input type="text" name="nombre">
 <br>
 <input type="submit" value="buscar">
    </form>
```

```
<?php

    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];

    echo "tu nombre es:", $nombre;

?>
```

Teniendo este código , el `HTML` al probarlo funciona correctamente pero  el archivo `PHP` me marca:

> Notice: Undefined index: nombre in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\procesaDatos.php on line 3

tu nombre es:

Comment: tienes un error tipográfico... en vez de un `,` en `echo "tu nombre es:", $nombre;` debes usar un `.` => `echo "tu nombre es:".$nombre;`... voto por cerrar error tipográfico

Comment: lo corregí , pero me sigue marcando lo mismo

Comment: Sustituye como ya te han mencionado el `,` por él `.` ya que no estas concatenado bien, e intenta resetear tu variable `$nombre` al principio del código, algo así, `$nombre  =  NULL;`

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que darle el id="nombre" en tu codigo html

```
<input type="submit" value="buscar" id="nombre">
```

Y el codigo PHP NO ES ASI `echo "tu nombre es:", $nombre;`
No es una coma, es asi:

```
echo "tu nombre es:" . $nombre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes de colocar el atributo `name` en el input de tipo submit, y el metodo `isset()` para validar lo que enviaste por `$_POST[]`

Ej:

```
<input name="btnEnviar" type="submit" value="Enviar"/>

if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar´])) {
   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
}
```

Eso deberia de resolver el problema

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios problemas en tu código, primero que nada estás asignando un valor de una variable no definida a $nombre en

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'] // <- Incorrecto
```

Intenta validar si la variable POST tiene contenido con un if y
 la función isset que devolverá true si la variable POST ya está inicializada, además, para concatenar en PHP no se utiliza la coma, para eso deberías de poner un punto, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
     if( isset($_POST['nombre']) ) {
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        echo "Tu nombre es: ".$nombre;
     }
?>
```